# scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition: not work in autolayout

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, autolayout, uistoryboard

Storyboard with autolayout

```
self.couponTableViewHeightConstraint.const = [self.coupons count] * cellHeight;
[self.couponTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath
                                    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                                            animated:NO];
```

Not work!

Answer (score 0):

Because change constaints can not change the tableview's frame!

Should use contentOffset like this:

```
self.couponTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, (int)currentIndex * cellHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath` be sure you don't use it in `viewdidload` or `viewwillappear`. Otherwise you are calling the method before `uitableview` is rendered.

Use it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.